# When Does It Make Sense To Rewrite A Python Module in C?

Tags: python, c, optimization

In a game that I am writing, I use a 2D vector class which I have written to handle the speeds of the objects. This is called a large number of times every frame as there are a lot of objects on the screen, so any increase I can make in its speed will be useful.

It is pretty simple, consisting mostly of wrappers to the related math functions. It would be quite trivial to rewrite in C, but I am not sure whether doing so will make any significant difference as all it really does is call the underlying math functions, add, multiply or divide.

So, my question is under what circumstances does it make sense to rewrite in C? Where will you see a significant speed boost, and where can you see a reasonable speed boost without rewriting an extensive amount of the program?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're vector-munging, give [numpy](https://numpy.org/) a try first. Chances are you will get speeds not far from C if you utilize numpy's vector manipulation functions wisely.

Other than that, your question is very heuristic. If your code is too slow:

1. Profile it - chances are you'll be able to improve it in Python
2. Use the correct optimized C-based libraries (numpy in your case)
3. Try `psyco`
4. Try rewriting parts with `cython`
5. If all else fails, rewrite in C

Answer (score 10):

First measure then optimize

Comment: Amen.  Optimization without benchmarks is just voodoo.  Designing with voodoo leads to bad software.  That said, developing some intuition about where to benchmark is important, and that is sort of what this question is asking.

Comment: Yes - I assumed other people with more personal experience would weigh in with numpy, boost:python, cython etc. I just thought I would hammer home the point

Comment: -1 'Chances are you will get speeds not far from C if you utilize numpy's vector manipulation functions wisely.' 

Where 'not far' actually means: 'not even close, but somewat satisfactory'.

Answer (score 1):

You should never optimize anything, be it in C or any other language, without timing your code before *and* after your optimization:

- your clever optimization could in fact induce a slow down
- optimizing something that takes 1% of the total execution time will never give you more than 1% performance

The common approach is:

1. profile your code
2. identify a hotspot
3. time this hotspot
4. optimize it
5. time the hotspot again, see if it's faster. If it's not goto 3.

If you can't find hotspots it could mean that your app is already optimized, or that you are not using the good algorithm for your problem. In both cases profiling helps understanding what your code does.

For profiling python code under Linux, you can use [pyprof2calltree](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyprof2calltree/) which works in conjunction with [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html), and is totally awesome.

Answer (score 0):

A nice Profiler I use on Linux is [pycallgraph](https://web.archive.org/web/20130909080528/http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/) - however, as your program gets bigger it starts to create much larger images which are harder to trace. I'm pretty sure you can exclude modules, though.

Answer (score 0):

Common wisdom is "profile", "measure", etc. Well - maybe. Just get in the debugger and take 10 [stackshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion/1562802#1562802). If more than one of them terminates in your wrapper code, then it is costing more than 10% roughly, so you should consider re-doing it in C, to save that time. Chances are you will find other things also that are costing more than that.